# hashing API key with a timestamp?

Tags: hash

I'm working on a project where the initial dev decided it would be a good idea to disguise API keys by md5'ing them with along with the current *minute*, and grant clients a three-minute window to send that value.

So the client does:

```
headers.authKey = md5(ACTUAL_API_KEY + current_minute())
```

And the server does:

```
// allow for one-minute-late and one-minute-early hashes
for (i in [-1, 0, 1]) :
  if headers.authKey == md5(ACTUAL_API_KEY + (current_minute()+i))
    valid = true
```

This seems like security theater to me. I guess I could entertain the idea that disguising the value "over the wire" might be a good idea, but I'm not sure if there is a real practical benefit to that, and it seems like it could be making things more complicated than they need to be. Also...md5.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't completely useless.  It does provide one bit of protection: an attacker who steals the value of `authKey` for some session only gets to exploit it for a very narrow time window.  In fact, what your coworker is doing very much resembles [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm)—the familiar system of time-based six-digit codes used as a second authentication factor.

Here's one scenario: an attacker manages to steal log files that reveal `authKey` values.  Without the timestamp thrown into the mix they could just reuse that value, possibly indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Security theater is about right. If it needs to be obscured "over the wire" it should be communicated over https or a similar, standard, encrypted tunnel. Anyone who can sniff the md5'ed "key" over the wire can just send it within the minute window.

And while it is reasonable to be dismissive of md5 for a number of reasons, if you assume there were some legit reason to do what the developer did, md5 isn't the problem. The weakness of md5 is the ability to generate collisions in hashes. As a hash to obscure some data, it's fine. But as you've pointed out, obscuring data doesn't buy you anything in this case.

The correct answer is to communicate the api key over a secured (e.g. TLS) channel. If you need the time limiting factor, you'd need to invalidate and re-issue new API keys, only good for a fixed period of time.

Comment: As a hash to obscure _sufficiently random_ data it's fine. But even so, better to just use `SHA-256` at this point (where it's actually useful to hash at all, of course).